# Windows 8 Git Bash - Command Push - Putty cache

Tags: git, git-push, pageant

I have installed Git on Windows 8.
The SSH key is uploaded to bitbucket.

Git works well (git status, git commit, etc.)

When I do a pull, git tells me:

```
$ Git push origin --all -u
```

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You have no
>   guarantee That the server is the computer you think it is. The
>   server's rsa2 key fingerprint is: ssh-rsa 2048 97: 8c: 1b: f2: 6f: 14:
>   6b: 5c: 3b: ec: aa: 46: 46: 74: 7c: 40 If you Trust this host, enter
>   "and" to add the key to PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting. If you
>   want to carry on connecting just once, without adding the key to the
>   cache, enter "n". If you do not Trust this host, press Return to
>   abandon the connection. Store key in cache? (Y / n)

By saying yes, he stays is frozen.

I have done the same from SourceTree and passes exactametne same, with the same error message.

In parallel I reviewed Pageant (PuTTY Authentication Agent), and I added the corresponding key (I tested SSH-1 (RSA) and SSH-2 RSA)

In both cases I still have the same problem ... do not let me push. Forever in the same place trying to cache the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try connecting to SSH separately first.

With OpenSSH, this would be:

```
ssh git@bitbucket.org
```

With PuTTY, you need to use `Plink` instead:

```
plink.exe git@bitbucket.org
```

This should give you the fingerprint prompt separately outside of Git, so hopefully it works then.

Comment: I tried it and it worked properly.
Thank you so much!!